# Правильный Port Forwarding

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, iptables

Мне непонятна одна вещь в Port Forwarding, может кто-нибудь объяснит понятным языком.

Есть рабочее правило (1):

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443,2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1`

И есть правило (2):

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 10.0.0.1 --sport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.1:80`

Мне не понятно в последнем правиле - POSTROUTING, привило подмены серого на белый - оно в целом действительно нужно? Вроде и без него все работает. И правильно ли написано в таком случае первое правило с multiport? Какие могут быть последствия если не указывать POSTROUTING?

Comment: мотивация здесь неплохо описана: https://it.wikireading.ru/14358 … Если в двух словах, то оно нужно чтобы был доступ к серверу из его же подсети по внешнему адресу…

Comment: К предыдущему комментарию. 

Если вы, например, из сети 10.0.0.0/24 а именно с IP 10.0.0.5 например обратитесь к  адресу  1.1.1.1:80 то запрос в итоге согласно правилам получит сервер 10.0.0.1 на порту 80. Дальше он обработает запрос и отправит ответ, а в силу того что  10.0.0.5  находится в одной подсети то маршрутизатор без последнего правила отправит пакет непосредственно ему.

Однако 10.0.0.5 ждет ответа от 1.1.1.1 , а не от 10.0.0.1 и само собой этот запрос работать не будет в итоге.